# Why $|P \oplus P^{'}| = |P| + |P^{'}| - |P \cap P^{'}|$ in Hopcroft & Karp's article? $|P \oplus P^{'}| = |P| + |P^{'}| - 2 |P \cap P^{'}|$.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am reading “An $n^{\frac{5}{2}}$ Algorithm for Maximum Matchings in Bipartite Graphs” by Hopcroft and Karp.

In the proof of THEOREM 2, the authors wrote $|P \oplus P^{'}| = |P| + |P^{'}| - |P \cap P^{'}|$.

But I think $|P \oplus P^{'}| = |P| + |P^{'}| - 2 |P \cap P^{'}|$ is correct.

[image]

Comment: If $P=P'$ then your version is correct. The only case where the two versions are both correct is when $|P\cap P'|=0.$

Comment: Linking the paper [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7e8b/7a7cf3e4954fdacc36db60829ee620e77c96.pdf) for anyone interested. I'm particularly confused by what is meant by a *shortest* augmenting path. Isn't the shortest augmenting path a single unmatched edge in a matching that is non-maximal? In which case your formula looks correct (not sure when it is wrong).

Comment: Indeed, non-maximal matchings have shortest augmenting path length 1. Also, your formula is the correct one because by augmenting $P$ by $P'$, we mean taking $P\cap P'$ out and inserting $P'\setminus P$. Whence you actually get an even stronger statement :)